# How can we extract intersecting key and its intersecting values of 2 objects in JS?

Tags: object, intersection

For Example:

const a={color:[red, green, blue],fruits:[apple, banana]}

const b ={color:[red, black, blue]}

someFucntion(a,b);
//result { color:[red, blue] }

Considering there could be any number of keys with the value of any length of the array. Please help me find the perfect solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One of my colleagues gave me the following function and this is what I was exactly looking for.

```
//Making the assumption that all values are arrays.
//Probably a more efficient way of doing this.
const a = { color: ["red", "green", "blue"], fruits: ["apple", "banana"] };
const b = {color: ["red", "black", "blue"] };
console.log(someFucntion(a, b)); // result { color:[red, blue] }
function someFucntion(objOne, objTwo) {
    // Find intersecting keys and values and return them.
    let finalObj = {};
    // Only need to check one. If it isn't in here, it doesn't matter
    // if it is in the other.
    for (const key in objOne) {
        // Check if key is in other object.
        if (key in objTwo) {
            // Assumes all values are arrays.
            finalObj[key] = [];
            // Populate with shared values.
            objOne[key].forEach(el => {
                if (objTwo[key].includes(el)) {
                    finalObj[key].push(el);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    return finalObj;
}
```